# Having problems with serial port on linux, between avr and linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, avr, ftdi

Hello i am trying to communicate between an avr atmega32a and a linux distro.
I am using an ftdi chip on usb port (VCOM drivers etc)

I will post the codes in avr and linux but the code in avr works fine as i tested it on minicom.

I assume the problem here is my code on linux.
The basic problem is that it sometimes works, sometimes does not work.
I assume it has something to do with opening and closing of the file descriptor or the port itself.

Why am i saying this?

The code on avr does a simple thing. Waits for a button to get pressed and then starts sending "Hello world" forever.

So when using minicom it works just fine.

When i use my program for the first time and wait for the button to gets pressed i don't seem to be able to read anything from the port even if i press the button.

Then i open minicom and it starts reading right away (because button has been pressed). Then i close minicom, i open my program and it works fine....

It seems to be having problems with opening and closing the file (port) but i am not sure.
Anyways this thing is not stable enough.

Any help would be grateful.

What i want to write is to read continuously from the serial port.
Ive read about blocking read but when i try to implement it it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

UPDATE****
I just added an else if (wordsRead < 0) printf("Error reading\n");
it seems that it is getting -1 when reading for the first time but i dont get why is this happening
The problem is that when it properly reads from the port (after using the minicom for the first time)
i am getting many error readings between the "Hello world" prints....

Here is my code AVR only main function.

```
int main()
{
    uart_init();
    //Set A0-6 as input, A7 as output
    //Set as hexademical cause compiler does not support 0b
    DDRA = 0x80;;
    //Triggers up
    PORTA = 0xFF;

    while ((PINA & 0x1) == 1);
    //Led on
    PORTA &= 0x7F; 

    while (1){  
        uart_putstring("Hello world ");
    }
}
```

Here is my C code on linux.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    //Open Port  
    int fdSP= open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fdSP == -1){
        printf("Error opening serial port\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // create the struct
    struct termios options;

    //Preferences
    int BaudRate = 19200;

    //Set Baud Rate
    cfsetispeed(&options, BaudRate);
    cfsetospeed(&options, BaudRate);

    //Set Parity (No Parity)
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;

    //Set Stop Bits (2 Stop Bits)
    options.c_cflag &= CSTOPB;

    //Set Data Bits (8 Data Bits)
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;


    if (tcsetattr(fdSP, TCSANOW, &options) != 0){
        printf("Error applying settings to serial port\n");
        return 1;
    }



    //Read Port
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        printf("Error creating child\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0){
        raise(SIGSTOP);
        int wordsRead;
        char readSP;
        while (1){
            wordsRead = read(fdSP, &readSP, 1);
            if (wordsRead > 0)
                printf("%c", readSP);
                    else if (wordsRead < 0)
                            printf("Error reading\n");
           }
    }
    else{
        printf("Created a child to read from serial port\n");
        printf("To kill the child open another terminal and type sudo kill %ld or press enter ok?", (long) pid);
        getchar();
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        getchar();
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);

        if (close(fdSP) == -1){
            printf("Error closing port\n");
            return 1;
        };
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why fork? Try to remove the fork and run it without to make the problem space smaller.

Comment: Are the port settings correct? `minicom` sets the settings the first time, then your program uses these. You might be missing something there.

Comment: You should use `tcgetattr` first to fill the `termios` struct. It is full of garbage now.

Comment: @BartFriederichs well i added fork so i could stop the whole process it does not seem to be the problem here. When i started working on this i had only one process to work on this. I could try it but i think ill be getting the same result

Comment: @BartFriederichs removed the fork it does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the problem...

Seems the problem was the order in which i was performing the whole thing about setting the attributes etc.

I changed the order to

1. Define the desired attributes -> options (new).
2. Open the serialport.
3. Get the existing attributes -> oldoptions.
4. Set the new attributes -> options (new).
5. Read from port.
6. Restore the old attributes -> oldoptions.
7. Close the port.

The order before (was not working) was(2->3->1->4->5->6->7)

Thanks @Bart Friederichs for his valuable advice and help

My final code is below

main (to be executed)

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sp-proc.h"

#define MY_BAUDRATE B19200


int main()
{
    // create the struct
    struct termios options, oldoptions;


    memset(&options,0,sizeof(options));
    options.c_iflag = 0;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_cflag = CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    //Setting Baud Rate
    cfsetispeed(&options, MY_BAUDRATE);
    cfsetospeed(&options, MY_BAUDRATE);

    //Open Serial Port  
    int fdSP = openSP();

    //Save old options to oldoptions
    getOldAttr(fdSP, &oldoptions);

    //Set new options
    setNewAttr(fdSP, &options, &oldoptions);

    //Create child to read from port
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        printf("Error creating child\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0){

        raise(SIGSTOP);
        //Read Port
        int wordsRead;
        char readSP;
        while (1){
            wordsRead = read(fdSP, &readSP, 1);
            if (wordsRead > 0)
                printf("%c", readSP);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("Created child with pid = %ld to read from Serial Port\n", (long) pid);
        printf("To stop reading from serial port open another terminal ");
        printf("and type sudo kill %ld or press <enter> ok?", (long) pid);
        getchar();
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        getchar();
        kill(pid, SIGSTOP); 
        printf("\n");

        //Restoring old options
        resetOldAttr(fdSP, &oldoptions);
        //Closing SerialPort
        closeSP(fdSP);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

sp-proc.h

```
int openSP(void);
void closeSP(int fd);
void getOldAttr(int fd, struct termios* old);
void resetOldAttr(int fd, struct termios* old);
void setNewAttr(int fd, struct termios* new, struct termios* old);
```

sp-proc.c

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int openSP(){
    int fd= open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("Error opening serial port\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return fd;
}

void closeSP(int fd){
    if (close(fd) == -1){
            printf("Error closing port\n");
            exit(1);
    }
}

void getOldAttr(int fd, struct termios* old){
    if (tcgetattr(fd, old) != 0){
        printf("Error getting old options from serial port\n");
        closeSP(fd);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void resetOldAttr(int fd, struct termios* old){
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, old) != 0){
        printf("Error restoring old options\n");
        closeSP(fd);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void setNewAttr(int fd, struct termios* new, struct termios* old){
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, new) != 0){
        printf("Error applying settings to serial port\n");
        resetOldAttr(fd, old);
        closeSP(fd);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
// create the struct
struct termios options;
```

creates an **uninitialized** `struct termios`. You should initialize with the current port settings first, then change the settings:

```
// create the struct
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(fdSP, &options);
```

Comment: Added it but im still having problems my minicom settings are Serial Device /dev/ttyUSB0, Lockfile Location /var/lock, Bps/Par/Bitss 19200 8N2, Hardware Flow Control No, Software Flow Control No

Comment: @BartDriederichs Seems you are right if i start minicom first it sets the serial port settings properly and then it works. The termios options are set properly (after i tcgetattr()), but how do i find out the proper termios options to set them?

Comment: @tchar check the settings minicom has. You could also try to read the options when it works.